# Как мне получить значение из динамически созданного Combobox?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, clr

Я новичок, моя программа создает Combox динамически, затем пользователь должен заполнить их. А программа должна записать их значения в Sring^. Не могу понять как мне к нему обратиться.

```
ComboBox^ comboBox = gcnew ComboBox();
comboBox->DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle::DropDownList;
comboBox->FormattingEnabled = true;
comboBox->Size = System::Drawing::Size(70);
comboBox->TabIndex = 2;
this->flowLayoutPanel1->Controls->Add(comboBox);

String^ txt;
ComboBox^ cbx = dynamic_cast<ComboBox^>(ctrl);
txt = (String^)cbx;
txt = cbx->SelectedText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ! Спасибо за внимание

```
String^ txt;
Object^ cbb = NULL;
cbb = ((System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox^)flowLayoutPanel1->Controls["ComBox" + Convert::ToString(y)])->SelectedItem;
txt = (String^)cbb;
```